# Identify type of database used on a host

Tags: database, port, host

Can we identify the type of database a host may be using by checking specific ports?
Also, is there anyway I can find out the database used on a server side, without having to log in to the server?

Comment: Want to do it through some code ?

Comment: yes. But i wanted to know, if there is any possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can port scan with nmap, it will tell you the open ports and what they belong to. (Though, if you're in a situation where you need to use nmap to determine which ports are open, then you're probably not on the same subnet and likely will be firewalled, resulting in nothing appearing open to you.)

Comment: So, unless we scan ports and sniff on the database activities, we cant check what database is used. is it?

Comment: You could ask the administrator.